# MU domain mapping without using a plugin

Tags: multisite, domain-mapping

**Context**:

After using some Domain Mapping plugins and having issues with all of them, I am wondering if I cannot just use a multi site with my own top-level domains in a safe way, without using any plugins for it.

I researched out there and all I find is outdated information that's unclear and doesn't help but unhelp.

**Question**:

Is it alright and safe to:

- set the site_url to whateverdomain.ftw in the db (for each site)

And just be okay with it?

Or is there something else I should consider?

**UPDATE**

How may I fix the fact that the admin area preserves the original url **when using the Domain Mapping plugin** (the one with the sunrise.php)?

Comment: probably the first question you should ask yourself is why do you want to use MU at all when you need different domains. And the answer to your question is NO.

Comment: @MarkKaplun I want to use MU because I use different domains for different sites that have the same purpose, and hence the same structure, plugins and theme. Using MU will allow a centralized update/changes management. Is this correct or should I still go for independent WP installions and why? - Also, why is it such a big no? Where and what is the thing that makes it a no? - Thank you.

Comment: The thing that make it a no (and the "no" refers just to your assertion that it might be an easy thing)is cookie management. If you want to admin the ite you need to use cookies with the root domain therefor differentdomain/wp-admin will not be enough to get you to the admin. There are several solutions but non of them is trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest even after your Update:

> How may I fix the fact that the admin area preserves the original url
>   **when using the Domain Mapping plugin** (the one with the sunrise.php)?

I don't quite understand whether you want to "*Redirect administration pages to network's original domain*" or not.

In any case, as per the [installation page](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/installation/):

> 4. "Redirect administration pages to network's original domain (remote
>      login disabled if this redirect is disabled)" - with this checked, if
>      a user visits their dashboard on a mapped domain it will redirect to
>      the dashboard on the non mapped domain. If you don't want this, remote
>      login will be disabled for security reasons.

There is also an abundance of even [youtube videos](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=wordpress+domain+mapping) that may help.